# Did they forget about the 'Restart' button, or was it just not important?

Tags: unity, restart, button

Seriously, from the top-right corner button, I have `Logout`, `Suspend`, `Hibernate` & `Shutdown` but shockingly no `Restart`.

What happened to the Restart button?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The restart button no longer shows up in that list. You need to select `Shut Down`.

In the confirmation box, it asks you if you want `Restart`, `Cancel` or `Shut Down`

**Screenshots for better understanding**

[image: How to choose shutdown]

[image: Choosing restart from shutdown confirm box]

Comment: Yup, thanks. I Did not notice it the first time.

Comment: Users that use the suppress_logout_restart_shutdown switch will not be able to restart by using the Session-Menu. This is a bug in my opinion.

Comment: @Chad--24216 what switch is that and how is it a bug? It sounds like you just said that users who disable the restart button won't be able to restart using the restart button.

Comment: @jeremy-bicha It is actually [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-session/+bug/828019), but I don't think it is a big problem. When you mess up with default settings, you should expect some side-behaviour

Comment: @chad-24216 The highest priority is to get the defaults working perfectly. The chances of failures increase as you keep on adding configuration options. At some point, making a system fool-proof isn't possible or just takes too much work. If you really want to supress it and still be able to logout, use Unity Dash and search for `Logout`

Comment: Okay, here's the thing. I have that setting set the way Chad mentioned. I can't figure out how to change it -- it isn't where it's supposedly supposed to be in gconf-editor. So, now, I actually have no idea how to restart my computer. It's pretty annoying to shut down and start up again.

Comment: @daniel Did you set that flag yourself? By default it is not set

Comment: @ManishSinha -- I imagine I did. Can't remember, though. I certainly can't remember how to fix it.

Comment: @Daniel AFAIK it is in dconf-editor